# DNS Error in syslog whenever I open PHPSTORM which causes VPN to stop working

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn

I am working from home like many others and I use A VPN to connect to my works network. It is somewhat spotty for me even though all my coworkers who use windows or MAC have no issues. I noticed that when I opened PHPSTORM the vpn connection cut out and it took about 5 re-connect tries for it to finally connect. This is frustrating as it happens a few times a day with other programs as well. Today I got this error and I am wondering if you all could help me troubleshoot so I can have a more stable VPN connection. Thank you.

Error 1:

```
Apr 22 07:01:24 jetbrains-toolbox.desktop[3705]: [0422/070124.934000:ERROR:dns_config_service_posix.cc(434)] DNS config watch failed.
Apr 22 07:01:24 jetbrains-toolbox.desktop[3705]: [0422/070124.938034:ERROR:dns_config_service_posix.cc(434)] DNS config watch failed.
Apr 22 07:01:24 jetbrains-toolbox.desktop[3705]: [0422/070124.943203:ERROR:dns_config_service_posix.cc(434)] DNS config watch failed.
Apr 22 07:01:24 jetbrains-toolbox.desktop[3705]: [0422/070124.947317:ERROR:dns_config_service_posix.cc(434)] DNS config watch failed.
Apr 22 07:01:24 jetbrains-toolbox.desktop[3705]: [0422/070124.951478:ERROR:dns_config_service_posix.cc(434)] DNS config watch failed.
Apr 22 07:01:24 jetbrains-toolbox.desktop[3705]: [0422/070124.955585:ERROR:dns_config_service_posix.cc(434)] DNS config watch failed.
Apr 22 07:01:24 jetbrains-toolbox.desktop[3705]: [0422/070124.959729:ERROR:dns_config_service_posix.cc(434)] DNS config watch failed.
Apr 22 07:01:24 jetbrains-toolbox.desktop[3705]: [0422/070124.963884:ERROR:dns_config_service_posix.cc(434)] DNS config watch failed.
Apr 22 07:01:24 jetbrains-toolbox.desktop[3705]: [0422/070124.969012:ERROR:dns_config_service_posix.cc(434)] DNS config watch failed.
Apr 22 07:01:24 jetbrains-toolbox.desktop[3705]: [0422/070124.972154:ERROR:dns_config_service_posix.cc(434)] DNS config watch failed.
Apr 22 07:01:24 jetbrains-toolbox.desktop[3705]: [0422/070124.977292:ERROR:dns_config_service_posix.cc(434)] DNS config watch failed.
Apr 22 07:01:24 jetbrains-toolbox.desktop[3705]: [0422/070124.980398:ERROR:dns_config_service_posix.cc(434)] DNS config watch failed.
```

System specific information:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Comment: Okay I added the information you requested @K7AAY